localbitcoins Tag for LocalBitcoins.com
My suggestion is to create a tag called 'Localbitcoins' or 'Localbitcoins.com' for users with questions about the Local Bitcoins website. This could potentially conflict with the local tag, however I believe that the local tag could be broadened to cover all forms of buying bitcoins locally be it through a website or btc-otc etc.

I have added a localbitcoins, however most questions dealing explicitly with localbitcoins are not tagged, yet.

I'll start tagging those questions (well, suggesting that they be tagged)
